# Why does python append a modulo(%) operator to the end of a newly opened file?

Tags: python, file, append, modulo

I'm experiencing some weird behavior from python's with statement, and I was hoping someone could clarify for me what is happening.

```
with open('hello.py', 'ab+') as f:
    f.write('hello=3')
```

Basically I am trying to create/open a python file, and append a new variable declaration to it. But the output of cat gives me this:

```
hello=3%
```

If instead of the above code I use:

```
with open('hello.py', 'ab+') as f:
    f.write('hello=3\n')
```

The modulo operator disappears. What gives?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is the`%` of your shell prompt, adding a new line puts it on the next line. It looks "weird" like that because its on the same line with your shell prompt.

Some shells like `sh` and `csh` do not add a new line before printing the new prompt. From the `%` shell prompt it looks like this is `csh` (c-shell)

Comment: Wow I hadn't realized that. I'm using ZSH though, and I do get a newline for the new prompt. Might be some conflict with my zsh settings I guess? Thank you!

Comment: @Psycheas: Unix assumes files text files end with `\n` - when you `cat hello.py`, cat only prints out the line breaks in the file. This results in a prompt appended on the (assumed empty) last line of the output.